# python print between two patterns, including lines containing patterns

Tags: python

I need to open a log file, and print out specific lines that are in between two different patterns.

```
Beginning = pattern1
Ending = pattern2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
       def SeeIfDateTimeIsFound():
           mylist = []
           for line in input_data:
               if CTFBeginA in line:  # Or whatever test is needed
                   if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                       mylist.append((line.strip()))
                       break
           for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
                   if CTFEndinA in line.strip():
                       nextline = (next(input_data, '').strip())
                       if CTFEndin not in nextline:
                           break
                       else:
                           if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                               mylist.append((line.strip()))
                           if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                               mylist.append((line.strip()))
           return mylist
```

What I'm trying to do is basically the equivalent of this awk code:

```
awk '/Beginning/,/Ending/' logfile
```

One of the problems i have with the python code above is, it only grabs the first line it finds that contains Ending pattern.  If there are multiple lines containing Ending, i want the python code to grab every one of them and only stop grabbing them when it has grabbed the last one.

Comment: i have updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

You could do something on these line:

```
print_swt = 0
with open(logfile,'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         if Beginning in line:
            print_swt =1
         if Ending in line:
            print_swt = 0

         if print_swt:
            print line
```

Note: This may not be the most `pythonic` way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: i have updated my original post. the previous code i had there was one of the many attempts i was making to fix this.  please review.